# Why does it have 5 async methods in MVC. IHttpAsyncHandler,IAsyncController,IAsyncActionInvoke,AsyncControllerDescriptor,AsyncActionDescriptor,

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, action, threadpool

In the asp.net web form we will use the `IHttpAsyncHandler` to hang the work thread in threadpool then have a new thread to do the IO cost(let's say it as an io thread). The work thread will be wake up until the IO thread end. So it will help the interaction of web server.

So why are there 4 more `async` method added in asp.net mvc? 
What is the main purpose for each of them? Could you please tell me the detail reasons?

PS: the asp.net 4 is support the `Task` actions now(TAP). As I learn, the task is also work in the threadpool, so is it influence the coming requests which are running in the threadpool tool?

Thank you my friends!

Below is the latest status:

1,IHttpAsyncHandler is also realized in MVC. The MVCHandler is inhert the IHttpAsyncHandler interface and IHttphandler. MVCHandler is manage the lifecycle of controller.

2, IAsyncController you can realize asyncaction on it.

3, IAsyncActionInvoke can only used on the controller which interited from IAsyncController

Let’s put the IHttpAsyncHandler aside for a moment. If we have a AsyncController before why we have to create a AsyncAction.
 The asynccontroller is already provide the BeginExecute and EndExecute for us. One reason I can only guess is that we need to 
 Control  the action running  In  another thread or not manually. 
4, IAsyncControllerDescriptor: provide the controllerdescriptor for AsynControllers. May be we can add more controller description by configuration. I'm not sure.

5,IAsyncActionDescriptor: provider the actiondescriptor for asyncactions. May be we can add more action description by configuration. I'm not sure.

David Peng

Comment: what is PTA? Do you mean Task Based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP)?

Comment: I reedited the post again. It's IHttpAsyncHandler. Thank you my friend.